# Best way to call and add/clear contacts in android instrumentation tests

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

What is he best way to add/clear contacts, start calls and register/unregister phone accounts for android instrumentation/emulator tests.

I do not want to add any kind of permissions such as `WRITE_CONTACTS` or anything like that to my test manifests.